# Python ldap3 LDAPSocketOpenError unable to send message, socket is not open

Tags: python, windows, centos, ldap, openldap

I am coding in Python, ldap3 trying to create a user in OpenLDAP on CentOS.
My local development machine is running Windows 8 64bit.
Below is my code.

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL

# define the server
s = Server('ldap://ldap.abcd.com:389', get_info=ALL)  

# define the connection
c = Connection(s, user='cn=Manager,dc=mydomain,dc=com', password='Super1')

# perform the Add operation
c.add('uid=user3,ou=People,dc=abcd,dc=com',['person','organizationalPerson','inetOrgPerson', 'posixGroup', 'top','shadowAccount'], {'givenName': 'user3firstname','sn': 'user3lastname', 'uidNumber' : 520,'gidNumber' : 521,'uid': 'user3','cn': 'user3user3lastname'})

# close the connection
c.unbind()
```

The Server and Connection class is working ok. i guess because if i run only that 2 statements, it didn't generate an error below.

```
LDAPSocketOpenError at /adminservice/users/
unable to send message, socket is not open
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/adminservice/users/
Django Version: 1.8.4
Exception Type: LDAPSocketOpenError
Exception Value:    
unable to send message, socket is not open
Exception Location: C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\ldap3\strategy\base.py in send, line 299
Python Executable:  C:\Python35\python.exe
Python Version: 3.5.1
Python Path:    
['D:\\sourcecode\\idp',
 'D:\\sourcecode\\utils-drf-public-api',
 'C:\\Python26',
 'C:\\Python35\\python35.zip',
 'C:\\Python35\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python35\\lib',
 'C:\\Python35',
 'C:\\Python35\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 13 May 2016 17:02:08 +0700
```

[image]

Answer (score 16):

You must bind the connection before adding the user. Try [`c.bind()`](https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bind.html?highlight=%60bind#the-bind-operation) before the add statement.